# Vowels followed by consonant and mute "e"

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

When I was learning English, a long time ago, I was taught that a vowel was long only if followed by a single consonant and a mute "e", as in mete and fate.  However, I find enough exceptions to this to make me question my memory of the rule.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: That vowel you thought was long is actually a diphthong! Time to bone up on the [**Great Vowel Shift**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e) and other fun stuff!

Comment: You learn a lot of crazy rules about English: *i* before *e* except after *c*. Don't end a sentence in a preposition. Don't say *ain't*. These are at best generalizations.

Comment: Extra credit: for a migraine, try [**-ough**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ough_(orthography))!

Answer (score 1):

Generally a vowel letter is read "long" (actually a diphthong in most cases, as P E Dant says) when it is followed by a single consonant letter and then another vowel letter. Your "single consonant and mute 'e'" is a special case of this. This explains, for example, 'cubic' as well as 'cube', and 'mating' versus 'matting'.

In one direction the rule has few exceptions: a single vowel letter followed by more than one consonant is almost always read "short". But for this purpose you need to regard 'th' (and sometimes 'sh' and 'ch') as single letters.

The other way round, there are rather more exceptions, many of them due to [trisyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing) - 'insanity' vs 'insane', for example. But that too has exceptions.